# How do I use values within a list to specify changing selection conditions and export paths?

Tags: pandas, loops, export-to-csv

I'm trying to split a large csv data using a condition. To automate this process, I'm pulling a list of unique conditions from a column in the data set and wanting to use this list within a loop to specify condition and also rename the export file.

I've converted the array of values into a list and have tried fitting my function into a loop, however, I believe syntax is the main error.

```py
# df1718 is my df
# znlist is my list of values (e.g. 0 1 2 3 4)
# serial is specified at the top e.g. '4' 


for x in znlist:
    dftemps = df1718[(df1718.varname == 'RoomTemperature') & (df1718.zone == x)]
    dftemps.to_csv('E:\\path\\test%d_zone(x).csv', serial)
```

So in theory, I would like each iteration to export the data relevant to the next zone in the list and the export file to be named test33_zone0.csv (for example). Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

The error I am getting is: "delimiter" must be string, not int

Comment: so what is the question ? show error you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the error is in saving the file try this

```
 dftemps.to_csv('E:\\path\\test{}_zone{}.csv'.format(str(serial),str(x)))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. If I understand correctly it was a case of converting the integer list into a string?

Comment: so if you want to pass some data in string so use .format()  and should convert int or float dtype into string

Comment: if you feel the answer is correct kindly approve it so that more people can benefit from the answer